# ¿Como hago para que no se pueda escribir en el datepicker?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy programadno en react y estoy usando un datepicker que encontre en internet y lo instale. El problema es que no quiero que se pueda escribir la fecha en el input, solo que el usuario pueda seleccionar la fecha a traves del calendario. Para esto uso disabled="true" pero no solo no se puedo escribir en el input sino que tampoco aparece el calendario para elegir la fecha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor es que uses el atributo readOnly={true} o simplemente readOnly, revisa si el datepicker soporta eso, que te permite poner el input de solo lectura, sin bloquearte el input.

Comment: Era eso. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Si es un input, agregale la propiedad `readonly`:

```html
<input readonly id="miId" name="miname"/> Intenta escribirme
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!